# SCP over VPN with SSH from Japan with server in Paris

Tags: macos, ssh, vpn, scp

I have a small problem with a connection to a secured server through VPN. I contacted the server admin but couldn't help me...

I'm located in Japan, and trying to access a server in France through VPN, with an SSH connection.

Everything is extremely slow, when I do the "traceroute IP" I have an average 400ms response. For instance all SCP transfer get stalled, this in a problem for me to work.

By any chance, someone knows if I can do something, or should I learn how to live like that ? :)

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to do. If it's only copying files, rsync over ssh might be a lot easier than scp via vpn over ssh.

Comment: Possibly your VPN provider is throttling, or the VPN is used very heavily, so it's at the limit of its bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Your traffic is, at a minimum, going from Japan to France and back again. Geographically, that's pretty much half way around the world, *twice*. In terms of Internet link distance, it may be farther, depending on what international links are available at the time.

If the VPN concentrator is located somewhere other than Japan or France, then the distance from the VPN concentrator (the host that accepts your VPN connection, and to which the connection is encrypted due to the VPN) to the target host is going to add to the delay.

When traceroute reports 400 ms, that means that the *roundtrip* time is 400 ms. In other words, from you, to the host in question, and back to you again along a similar if not the same path. The VPN itself may also add some slight overhead, but this should be minimal with modern hardware.

When I traceroute from Sweden to a random host in Japan, I get roundtrip times of about 275 ms. For comparison, I have roundtrip times of about 30-35 ms to France.

So while 400 ms roundtrip between Japan and France appears high, it is not *immediately unreasonably high*. Based on this and some small amount of deductive reasoning, I would expect that a good link might give you roundtrip times in the range 250-300 ms.

**Try tracerouting to the server in France, or at least a server located as near it as you can, without going through the VPN, and see what roundtrip times you get. Chances are that they are going to be similar,** in which case you will unfortunately just have to live with the roundtrip times.

If there is a large difference in roundtrip times with and without VPN, consider whether it would be possible to route the SSH traffic (which is encrypted in itself) outside of the VPN somehow. In that case, also look into why the VPN is adding so much latency: ask the administrator to look for congestion in the VPN concentrator (usually evidenced by high CPU usage), and look at your local system to see if there is high CPU utilization that can be attributed to the VPN traffic or software.